# difference between to be N, A / N, A

Tags: complements

I have heard that cognitive verbs such as 'think, believe, consider, suppose, understand, imagine...etc.' should use 'to be noun' or 'to be adjective' in the object complement.

> She believed him to be a teacher.

> She considers him (to be) rich.

Or, there is a saying that 'to be' cannot be omitted before a noun, but 'to be' can be omitted before an adjective.

Which one is right?

1. Is 'to be' always something that can be omitted?
2. Please let me know if there is a subtle difference in meaning between the presence and absence of 'to be'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is already asked on EL&U.

Comment: @fev The presence of a question on another website is not a reason to close so far as I am aware. This question is arguably more suitable here anyway. I suspect there is plenty of duplication between the two sites, but the level of complexity in the answers, and their applicability to learners, may be very different.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that this is getting into a very technical aspect of English and is something most English speakers will not understand or care about.

In most cases you will want "to be". There are some cognitive verbs with which it's acceptable to remove it, such as 'considers'. In the case of "she considers him to be rich", 'considers' is a much less common word to use compared to 'believes' or 'thinks', but is still correct.

> She believes that he is rich.

> She thinks that he is rich.

> She considers him to be rich.

> She considers him rich.